# How to have a content script function upon enabling the extension without reloading the web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome Extension development. I followed some of the tutorials and created an extension. The extension I am trying is to highlight the webelements on HOVER. My problem is that the extension works ONLY when the page loads. It does not work on the already opened active tab. I want to make sure that the extension works in the already opened active tab when clicking the icon.

Manifest:

```css
   
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "Highlight Web Element",
 "description": "Extension for highlighting element in a web page",
 "version": "1.0",
 "content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
   "css": ["core.css"],
   "js": ["contentscript.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end",
   "all_frames": false
  }
 ],
 "background" : {
  "scripts" : ["background.js"]
 },
 "browser_action": {
  //"default_icon": "logo .png"
 },
 "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"]
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "testScript.js"});   
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   console.log(sender);
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: request.greeting, "srcElementTagName" : request.srcElementTagName});
  });
```

contentscript.js

```js
// Unique ID for the className.
var MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME = 'plugin_crx_mouse_visited';

// Previous dom, that we want to track, so we can remove the previous styling.
var prevDOM = null;

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var srcElement = e.srcElement;
  if(prevDOM != srcElement) {
 //console.log(srcElement.tagName);
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello", "srcElementTagName" : srcElement.tagName}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell + " : " + response.srcElementTagName);
 });
  }
  // Lets check if our underlying element is a DIV.
  //if (srcElement.nodeName == 'DIV') {

 // For NPE checking, we check safely. We need to remove the class name
 // Since we will be styling the new one after.
 if (prevDOM != null) {
   prevDOM.classList.remove(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);
 }

 // Add a visited class name to the element. So we can style it.
 srcElement.classList.add(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);

 // The current element is now the previous. So we can remove the class
 // during the next iteration.
 prevDOM = srcElement;
  //}
}, false);
```

core.css

```css
.plugin_crx_mouse_visited {
  background-color: #bcd5eb !important;
  outline: 1px solid #5166bb !important;
}
```

I tried invoking the below code in testScript.js. But not successful.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   console.log(sender);
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: request.greeting, "srcElementTagName" : request.srcElementTagName});
  });
```

Comment: Hi Makyen - Thanks for your reply and sorry for misinterpreting my requirement. I thought that the icon will still be shown after disabling the extension from chrome://extensions. I have updated my question accordingly. Thanks..

Comment: Your actual issue appears to be that when an extension is loaded, Chrome does not inject any *manifest.json* specified `content_scripts` into tabs which are already open and match your `matches` pattern. Your code currently assumes that your *contentscript.js* script has already been injected prior to the `browserAction` button being clicked. There are multiple ways to resolve this. If your user interaction *begins* with the user clicking the `browserAction` button, then you should be injecting *contentscript.js* with `executeScript()` instead of from *manifest.json*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it resolved with the below approach. Thanks Makyen for your reply!!!

```css
{
        "name": "Invoke when Extension is Clicked",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "browser_action": {
   "name": "Click to get URL"
        },
        "background":{
            "scripts":["background.js"]
        },
        "permissions":["tabs", "activeTab"] //Put All your URL here
 }
```

background.js

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON
    
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "contentscript.js"
        }, function () { // Execute your code
            console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
        });
   
});
```

contentscript.js

```js
// Unique ID for the className.
var MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME = 'plugin_crx_mouse_visited';

// Previous dom, that we want to track, so we can remove the previous styling.
var prevDOM = null;

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var srcElement = e.srcElement;
  if(prevDOM != srcElement) {
 //console.log(srcElement.tagName);
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello", "srcElementTagName" : srcElement.tagName}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell + " : " + response.srcElementTagName);
 });
  }
  // Lets check if our underlying element is a DIV.
  //if (srcElement.nodeName == 'DIV') {

 // For NPE checking, we check safely. We need to remove the class name
 // Since we will be styling the new one after.
 if (prevDOM != null) {
   prevDOM.classList.remove(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);
 }

 // Add a visited class name to the element. So we can style it.
 srcElement.classList.add(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);

 // The current element is now the previous. So we can remove the class
 // during the next iteration.
 prevDOM = srcElement;
  //}
}, false);
```

Enabled the extension using chrome://extensions and when the Icon is clicked on the active tab, the extension got invoked and I was able to highlight the webelement.